# Evaluation order in polynomials

Tags: evaluation

I'm confused by the evaluation order of polynomials containing division. Consider these two polynomials:

```
(x^2 + y) z/w    (1)
a/b              (2)
```

And their tree form:

```
TreeForm[(x^2 + y) z/w]
```

[image]

```
TreeForm[a/b]
```

[image]

I understand that division is `x^-1` which has higher evaluation precedence. But why in the tree form, the power of `w^-1` (in the first polynomial) is in the first position, while `b^-1` (in the second polynomial) is in the second position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Times` has the Attributes [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless.html) and [`Flat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flat.html).  (Among others.)

`a/b` has the FullForm `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]`.  That is already in the sorted order:

```
Sort[{a, Power[b, -1]}]
```

> ```
> {a, 1/b}
> ```

And as there is only one `Times` the `Flat` attribute doesn't change anything.

However the first expression is interpreted as:

```
(x^2 + y) z/w // FullForm // HoldForm
```

> ```
> Times[Plus[Power[x,2],y],Times[z,Power[w,-1]]]
> ```

And then the `Times` expressions are combined (for `Flat`) and sorted (for `Orderless`):

```
Sort @ {Plus[Power[x, 2], y], z, Power[w, -1]} // FullForm
```

> ```
> List[Power[w,-1],Plus[Power[x,2],y],z]
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation!